# using comma in date format JSTL

Tags: jstl

I need to display date as -
December, 13 2013 in JSP

For this I am using -

```
<fmt:formatDate  value="${lastViewedDate}" var="viewedDate"  pattern="MMMM, dd yyyy" />
```

But it's not showing "," in date -
December 13 2013

Is it not possible in JSTL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove 'var' attribute:

```
<fmt:formatDate  value="${lastViewedDate}" pattern="MMMM, dd yyyy" />
```

it will print December, 13 2013 into your JSP

'var' attribute used if you want to store formatted date in a scope. Default scope is 'page' and nothing printed into JSP.